# Windows 11 - How to drag a Remote Desktop window to another monitor?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

On Windows 10, with two monitors, I could easily drag a Remote Desktop window from one monitor to another. On Windows 11, the Remote Desktop window won't drag at all - even to a new position on the same monitor.

Tried minimizing, maximizing, etc., when window is neither maximized nor minimized, the window will not drag at all. Trying to drag causes a delay, then a short jump of the window to a position in the direction of the drag, but only a short distance.

I can move it to a new monitor by right-clicking on the window title, choosing "Move" and then using the arrow keys to move the window, but that is a pain. What am I missing? Is there a magic setting somewhere?

Comment: And other applications, like browser, File Explorer or such? They can move?

Comment: What is your display/graphic adapter? For NVIDIA see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/427474/remote-desktop-will-not-go-on-dual-monitors-all-of). Are you on the latest Windows version? See some solutions [here](https://www.guidingtech.com/best-ways-to-enable-drag-and-drop-on-windows-11/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the RDP window isn't a standard RDP window.  It is somehow being shelled by a vendor application when I connect to a particular client VPN site.

I will contact the vendor for support.
The window just fails to respond to drag actions, but does respond to the Move menu option and can then be moved with the arrow keys.

RDP itself is working when I use it on other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

- open Remote Desktop Connection
- expand Show options
- go to Display and check "Use all my monitors for the remote session"